# How to concatenate 2D array with a chunk size

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following 2D array and I would like to find a way to generate another 2D array but with data concatened with a chunk size.

```
array_2d = [
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]
]
```

For example, with a chunk size of 2 the above 2D array will be changed to:

```
array_2d = [
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]
]
```

Note that the last element has been zero padded on the left.

Thanks for help.

Comment: [.](https://tio.run/##hZFRa8MgFIXf/RWXPGlnS@xeRiG/xIlItI1suxFjKO2fzzSkzI2xKQj3eL5zBMMtDSM@v4S4LNadwcSo@xF7k/TVp0EHY63HC806h36Y8U1P/u46wU4E8kJ31fkOOpBqFc5jBA8eIRq8ONpyeHdYcFbzG10lHEwIDi2d5o/ilv6UY54qRPFcwVjdKvdCleZWwQ7o1pMnlscvEPbrEyqGsZxczWtmdGmO@JAJyYe56aMtBUS2vN5C8X8kUfZPl/jdRRTZWh@Ff/zCauFwZCREj4k2suGw@8ZzaFQWJxe65hUbtiyf)

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by _data concatenated with a chunk size_?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

```
array_2d = [
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]
]

def chunkconcat(chunk, init_data):
    data_arr = init_data
    # padding
    while (len(data_arr) % chunk) != 0:
        data_arr.append([0 for _ in range(len(data_arr[0]))])
    # division into smaller chunks
    divide_data = [data_arr[i*chunk:(i+1)*chunk] for i in range(int(len(data_arr)/chunk))]
    print(divide_data)
    new_arr = []
    # use the slices by reversing order and concatenating them
    for slice in divide_data:
        tmp = []
        for ind in range(chunk):
            tmp.append(slice[-1])
            slice.pop()
        new_arr.append(np.concatenate(tmp))

    final_data = np.array(new_arr)
    print(final_data)

chunkconcat(2, array_2d)
```

So you can also follow the solution and build your own solutions based on this, I did it explicitly.

Basically you start by padding vectors of zeros to be able to do the wanted conversion/concatenation or however you want to call it.

Afterwards you divide the data set into smaller parts of your wanted chunksize. Reversing order and passing it to temporary list enables us to get the order right and concatenating them, afterwards we add the result to our final list ('matrix').

Converting it into a numpy array in a final step to have a real matrix.

Using predefined functions and list comprehensions you could solve this in few lines, but this would not be very helpful for you I guess.

Take care.

Comment: `[0 for _ in range(len(data_arr[0]))]` equal to `[0] * len(data_arr[0])`

Comment: You're using `numpy` just for array concatenation, instead of using it's functonality

Comment: `[data_arr[i*chunk:(i+1)*chunk] for i in range(int(len(data_arr)/chunk))]` equal to`[data_arr[i: i + chunk] for i in range(0, len(data_arr), chunk)]`

Comment: `tmp.append(slice[-1]) ; slice.pop()` equal to `tmp.append(slice.pop())`